# How can I fix / patch a bug in an executable without recompiling it?

Tags: .net, vb.net, runtime

I have written a VB.Net program however there is a bug in one of the methods.  I would like to fix the bug but I don't want to change the original executable.

I know I can override a referenced assembley using a configuration file, but is there a similar method to override a method in my executable?

I have reasons for not recompiling the original executable.

Comment: So you're asking how to fix a bug in an executable without changing the executable?

Comment: Compile a fixed version then generate & distribute a differential binary patch against the existing exe?

Comment: Its software so pretty much *anything* can be done, however as far as I am aware what you are asking for would be **incredibly** difficult (and would almost certainly be unsupported).  I don't know what your reasons are for not wanting to recompile your original exe however its almost certainly easier to solve that problem than trying to hot-patch a .Net method in this way.

Comment: What are the reasons for not recompiling?  If you code is protected in some sort of version control, you wouldn't have to worry about losing your original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Is there a similar method to override a method in my executable
```

No, there is no such method without modifying the exe